# How to troubleshot problems with placing my COM object to clipboard using OleSetClipboard?

Tags: c++, com, clipboard, ole

I am using `COM` technology to work with clipboard (I am doing this, because native clipboard does not fit my purposes) I have inserted object to clipboard (via `OleSetClipboard` function from c++ application). But inserted object does not work in other applications. For example, I decided to test it from c# application. But it shows that object contains no any data. How can I test my `com` objects? If to be more specifically, my object implements `IDataObject` interface. I tried to test object from c++ application, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MSDN article on debugging COM objects and respective debugging tools: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16akzk8h.aspx

Comment: Wow, I will check it out